# Building the Objective-C XML-RPC Framework for iOS

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, frameworks, ios-frameworks

I'm fairly new to the iOS SDK and Xcode and I stumbled across this XML-RPC framework https://github.com/eczarny/xmlrpc that I'd really like to use in one of my projects. I downloaded the sources, the initial target was set to Mac OS, so I changed that to iOS 4.3 but got the following dependency error:

```
target specifies product type 'com.apple.product-type.framework', but there's no such product type for the 'iphoneos' platform
```

So I removed all the targets and added a new one from scratch using the Cocoa Touch Static Library, and it seems like it's been built just fine. Now my question is whether this is the correct way to build that library for iOS development, and where do I take it from here? I can't find the .framework directory anywhere (the install dir was set to "@executable_path/../Frameworks") so I can't embed it in my iOS project. How exactly does this go? Thanks!

Thanks for your help and sorry if this is too "newbish". Cheers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using Xcode 4.x open the Organizer, select the Projects tab and then down the left hand side you should see an entry relating to the XML-RPC project. Select that and under the Derived Data heading you'll see a path which if you follow using finder *should* lead you to the folder containing the static library you've built.

Comment: Thanks! Found it, but the Products path is empty and the .a file appears to be red in the XMLRPC project after the build. Did I miss anything? Thanks again!

Comment: It being red would suggest that the build failed. Did you receive any error messages either in Xcode or the console? Did the '*Build Failed*' popup appear?

Comment: No, it said build was successful but libXMLRPC.a in Products is still red. Also Foundation.framework in Frameworks is red as well if that helps, but it says there "No Issues" so I'm wondering :)

Comment: I also tried setting the "Deployment location" for the target to YES and ended up with a broken link to libXMLRPC.a in my products folder. Hope this helps too.

Comment: I'm not totally sure then, and I don't have access to Xcode at the moment to check for myself. However, I've just had a quick look through the source, and there is an existing target for iOS called libXMLRPC so you may want to re-download the source, select that target and build it rather than using the target you've built yourself (*as the original one should be properly configured*). You may need to add the Targets drop-down to your Xcode toolbar manually first, by right-clicking on it and choosing customise.

Comment: Hey you totally rock! I realized I downloaded the 2.2.1 tag but the master branch, with all the targets was built without any errors and I was able to include the lib in my project. Thanks!

Comment: Your help would be much appreciated on this follow-up thread too: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6492322/building-xmlrpc-framework-wrong-architecture Thanks!